# Rename system folder using sql query in python

Tags: python, sql, directory, rename

I have made a power automate flow that runs when someone submit a Microsoft form, the result will create a folder of the name of the person who filled that form (Name field is mandatory in the form) and store the files into that folder he has attached at the time of filling the form. Names also gets updated in the database under xyz table. It is sure that if 10 people fill the form in a day then in database also there will be 10 rows added under Name column.

In xyz table there is one more column named surname. It also gets updated along with name column.
example below:

```
Name    Surname

David   Warner
Shane   Watson
```

What I want is to make a python script that check names from the database daily and change folder names to surname. Basically, the script will check if name = David then changes the folder name to Warner and if name = Shane then changes it to Watson and so on... I have no idea how to rename like this.

Comment: [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) should provide all you need for creating (`mkdir` or `mkdirs`) or moving (`rename`) directories. Do not rely on the names/surenames only – there might be duplicates (sometimes even the name + surename combination), you should consider this (e.g. additionally `David Miller` and `Simon Watson`).

Comment: For SQL queries you might find [this site](https://builtin.com/data-science/how-to-use-sql-python) interesting – or query your favourite search engine with `python sql` if it doesn't satisfy (just had a short glance at...), there are dozens of tutorials.

Comment: For testing on a daily basis: Store a timestamp (initial value minimum value possible) when the DB query has run last time, check current timestamp and if the difference is greater than 24h run the query again. Alternatively check for both timestamps if they indicate the same *day*, if not, run the db query. This way you'd always run the query at midnight. You could, too, subtract e.g. 3 hours from current timestamp then your query would run at 3 am.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for sharing. But let's say instead of names I have unique numbers in Name and Surname columns then how to rename it? I just want to rename the folders from the database as I said. Will os do this?

Comment: `os.rename` can be used to rename files *and* directories, so all you need is to find out which directory to give which new name...

Answer (score 1):

Actually it makes your work hard when some names may be duplicated and folder names can't be. I recommend you to use sth like unique primary key as auto increment and make folder for every id of users. In such case you don't need to change anything. It is a little bit hard to find out files but it is easy to implement.

Another way to implement sth like this is to structure folder based on Year/Month/Day of creation. This is organized and you can store the file path as another field in DB and easily access them.

Comment: Y/M/D likely is not precise enough, depending on frequency of visit some requests might clash even within same hour (minute, second, ...). The `id` approach appears much safer to me, requires no additional columns and is in general easier to implement (no updates after folder creation), so clearly superior...

Comment: @Aconcagua Of course you can use a combination of both. use id with a good folder structure like this: `Y/M/D/user_id`

Comment: Hm... Depends on the use case, though if date of creation actually is of interest I personally would rather prefer adding this one as additional column into the data base with the appropriate timestamp type and keep all user folders in the same parent directory. Makes iterating over all of these easier, if need be (can be done without database lookup then!).